# How to assert a value in an xml using karate

Tags: karate

I have below xml response and I need to assert for 'result' value using karate

```
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="num1">4</value>
  <value name="num2">3</value>
  <value name="n1">4</value>
  <value name="result">7</value>
  <value name="n2">3</value>
  <value name="value">7</value>
</Values>
```

I am able to get data for 'Values' object but not for 'result' element.

Comment: Hi Peter,  Still I did not get answer for this xml assertion

Comment: Yes Peter. I have accepeted it

Comment: Still waiting for your answer Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* def response = 
"""
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="num1">4</value>
  <value name="num2">3</value>
  <value name="n1">4</value>
  <value name="result">7</value>
  <value name="n2">3</value>
  <value name="value">7</value>
</Values>
"""
* match /Values//value[@name='result'] == '7'
```

Comment: Is this possible to do with a fuzzy match? match the response xml to the expected xml and looking for one element of the list to match, ignoring the other elements.